# Why does wp_redirect strip out %0A (url encoded new line character) and how do I make it stop?

Tags: redirect, urls, wp-redirect, sanitization, encoding

Does this have something to do with sanitization? I need to pass a string as a URL parameter, and that string has \n characters in it. When the URL gets to the client, all other encoding is there (spaces show up as +, colons show up as %3A, etc...), but not new lines.

Here is the relevant code:

```
wp_redirect("/upload_success?responseMsg=".urlencode($new_body->message));
```

Comment: Keep in mind that an attacker could insert arbitrary HTML into the `responseMsg` value and use that as an attack vector, and a very dangerous one at that. You should not pass the message via URL from the browser. Instead pass an identifier referring to whatever was uploaded so the PHP can figure out the message on its own

Comment: Also note that sanitising happens for a reason, it prevents a bypass vulnerability, see https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/4819 and https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/10226 what you're trying to do is fundamentally insecure

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look to the `wp_sanitize_redirect()` function you will notice it is removing the new lines from the destination URL:

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9/src/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L1249

In my opinion you have 2 options:

1 - Convert new lines on the message to a diff allowed unique char combination  and then replace them back to new lines before outputting the string from the `responseMsg` URL parameter.

2 - Since this is a [pluggable function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pluggable_Functions), you can put it on a plugin and customize it to fit your needs.
Something like this:

```
if ( !function_exists('wp_redirect') ) :
/**
 * Redirects to another page.
 *
 * Note: wp_redirect() does not exit automatically, and should almost always be
 * followed by a call to `exit;`:
 *
 *     wp_redirect( $url );
 *     exit;
 *
 * Exiting can also be selectively manipulated by using wp_redirect() as a conditional
 * in conjunction with the {@see 'wp_redirect'} and {@see 'wp_redirect_location'} hooks:
 *
 *     if ( wp_redirect( $url ) ) {
 *         exit;
 *     }
 *
 * @since 1.5.1
 *
 * @global bool $is_IIS
 *
 * @param string $location The path to redirect to.
 * @param int    $status   Status code to use.
 * @return bool False if $location is not provided, true otherwise.
 */
function wp_redirect($location, $status = 302, $strip_new_lines = true) {
    global $is_IIS;

    /**
     * Filters the redirect location.
     *
     * @since 2.1.0
     *
     * @param string $location The path to redirect to.
     * @param int    $status   Status code to use.
     */
    $location = apply_filters( 'wp_redirect', $location, $status );

    /**
     * Filters the redirect status code.
     *
     * @since 2.3.0
     *
     * @param int    $status   Status code to use.
     * @param string $location The path to redirect to.
     */
    $status = apply_filters( 'wp_redirect_status', $status, $location );

    if ( ! $location )
        return false;

    $location = wp_sanitize_redirect($location, $strip_new_lines);

    if ( !$is_IIS && PHP_SAPI != 'cgi-fcgi' )
        status_header($status); // This causes problems on IIS and some FastCGI setups

    header("Location: $location", true, $status);

    return true;
}
endif;

if ( !function_exists('wp_sanitize_redirect') ) :
/**
 * Sanitizes a URL for use in a redirect.
 *
 * @since 2.3.0
 *
 * @param string $location The path to redirect to.
 * @return string Redirect-sanitized URL.
 **/
function wp_sanitize_redirect($location, $strip_new_lines = true) {
    $regex = '/
        (
            (?: [\xC2-\xDF][\x80-\xBF]        # double-byte sequences   110xxxxx 10xxxxxx
            |   \xE0[\xA0-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]    # triple-byte sequences   1110xxxx 10xxxxxx * 2
            |   [\xE1-\xEC][\x80-\xBF]{2}
            |   \xED[\x80-\x9F][\x80-\xBF]
            |   [\xEE-\xEF][\x80-\xBF]{2}
            |   \xF0[\x90-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]{2} # four-byte sequences   11110xxx 10xxxxxx * 3
            |   [\xF1-\xF3][\x80-\xBF]{3}
            |   \xF4[\x80-\x8F][\x80-\xBF]{2}
        ){1,40}                              # ...one or more times
        )/x';
    $location = preg_replace_callback( $regex, '_wp_sanitize_utf8_in_redirect', $location );
    $location = preg_replace('|[^a-z0-9-~+_.?#=&;,/:%!*\[\]()@]|i', '', $location);
    $location = wp_kses_no_null($location);

    // remove %0d and %0a from location
    $strip = array('%0d', '%0a', '%0D', '%0A');
    return $strip_new_lines ? _deep_replace( $strip, $location ) : $location;
}

/**
 * URL encode UTF-8 characters in a URL.
 *
 * @ignore
 * @since 4.2.0
 * @access private
 *
 * @see wp_sanitize_redirect()
 *
 * @param array $matches RegEx matches against the redirect location.
 * @return string URL-encoded version of the first RegEx match.
 */
function _wp_sanitize_utf8_in_redirect( $matches ) {
    return urlencode( $matches[0] );
}
endif;
```

Then you can call:

```
// by default is removing new lines so we pass false
$strip_new_lines = false;
$location = "/upload_success?responseMsg=".urlencode($new_body->message);

// make sure you pass the correct HTTP 
// status here to prevent penalty or any  other SEO issue
$status = 302;

wp_redirect( $location, $status,  $strip_new_lines );
//  wp_redirect() does not exit automatically
exit;
```

Comment: Thanks @dave-romsey for the improvement on the answer